# Why do encryption things seem to hang?

Tags: networking

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian. Recently I've started having issues where things that require encryption seem to just hang. Specifically, ssh, or openssl connections (alpine, connecting to outlook365).

I know that it's the raspberry pi, because I can connect via ssh with *any* of my other machines and the ssh connection works totally fine. Phone. Linux box. Windows box. Mac. All fine.

My inbound SSH seems to work totally fine, I haven't had any problems. I've just tried debugging via strace, and it appears to hang right here:

```
write(3, "\0\0\0\20\4\341~C~\220\257\305\32,\236\232!\304G\310m{84vo}\210", 28) = 28
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {506828, 901079842}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {506828, 901347288}) = 0
select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL
```

which seems a bit odd to me. Later, it appeared that there are some other odd things happening with signals, but I'm not sure:

```
│--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
│rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {0x54b244a4, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x76c4f180}, 8) = 0
│sigreturn() (mask [])                   = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507149, 615418770}) = 0
│ioctl(4, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=23, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507149, 615817049}) = 0
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507149, 615969235}) = 0
│select(7, [3 4], [3], NULL, NULL)       = 1 (out [3])
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507149, 616360170}) = 0
│write(3, "\0\0\0000\362,w\24\3fD\243\305\177+\366\233s\324\266(\217\357\240\206\252\16+\
│310S\307\374"..., 60) = 60
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507149, 616803344}) = 0
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507149, 616949228}) = 0
│select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL)        = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handle
│r)
│--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
│rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {0x54b244a4, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x76c4f180}, 8) = 0
│sigreturn() (mask [])                   = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507152, 635402869}) = 0
│ioctl(4, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=51, ws_col=177, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507152, 635862033}) = 0
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507152, 636525466}) = 0
│select(7, [3 4], [3], NULL, NULL)       = 1 (out [3])
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507152, 636939630}) = 0
│write(3, "\0\0\0000W\323\370\242\271\216;\5\20\1\234\371]x\33&+\225\313X\177q\260\33\372
│\0209\345"..., 60) = 60
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507152, 637364262}) = 0
│clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {507152, 637534053}) = 0
│select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL
```

Any clue why this is happening, and more importantly, how to fix it?

Comment: The raspberry pi no longer accepts incoming ssh by default. You need to enable that. Could it be that you've got a new version of raspian and need to switch this over? (You said "inbound" is working fine, but I was confused by that part as to which machine you were on and so which way was "in".)

Comment: Nah, I've got that correctly configured. SSH in to the pi works fine, it's SSH to other servers from the pi that seems to choke. Eventually it fails with a broken pipe. Trying to see if more than one destination has problems.

Comment: How are you connecting your raspberry pi to the internet (ethernet/wifi) and is it connected directly to your router or through your computer?

Comment: Ethernet, through the router, like my other machines with no problems.